# How do I find words in nested lists?

Tags: python, list, search

I have a list of lists, where every item of the list is a quote, with an author. Taks as example the following list:

```
[ ['The baby\'s blood type? Human, mostly.' , 'Orson Scott Card']....]
```

I am trying to make a search program, so that a user can type in a word, and it will search in the lists and find the string of letters, (so that bab would result in the example being displayed), and then display the full quote along with the author (with formatting).

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I have no idea how to attempt it. I'm thinking looking for str of letters in the whole thing, then printing its list. But I don't know how to do that :/

Comment: Can you give more information on the data structure then? Is the quote always the first element of the list, do you want to be able to search by author or just quote?

Comment: [['With bloody hands, I say good-bye.'                    , 'Frank Miller'],
  ['TIME MACHINE REACHES FUTURE!!! ... nobody there ...'   , 'Harry Harrison'  ],...] The quote is always first.

Comment: I would like it to search the word and look for it in the quote, I would like to do a separate one for the author.

Answer (score 3):

First of, I recommend you use a named tuple to save the quote and author.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Quote = namedtuple('Quote', ['body', 'author'])
```

Then having a list of quotes, you would print the ones containing 'bab' like so:

```
for quote in quotes:
    if 'bab' in quote.body:
        print '"{}" - {}'.format(quote.body, quote.author)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sticking with the current data structure, you'll need to iterate over the list and then use str.find() to check if a string contains the intended word.

```
searchQuote = True
searchWord = "bab"
for quote in quotes:
    if searchQuote:
        if quote[0].find(searchWord) > -1:
            print ("{} - {}".format(quote[0],quote[1]))
    else:
        if quote[1].find(searchWord) > -1:
            print ("{} - {}".format(quote[0],quote[1]))
```

searchQuote is just a boolean you can set based on whether you're searching the author or quote.
If you want just one quote and not all results, add a break after the print command.